# Black screen on working X server

Tags: arch-linux, x11, nvidia, graphics

After a system Upgrade today (I run Arch linux), my X Server went black.

The system startup works fine, I'm even presented my ttys at the beginning, where I usually start X with startx. This works as well, it starts my xmonad and does everything else in my .xinitrc as writing test messages in files, only it is completely black. I can even *use* my xmonad, as I successfully executed commands blindly in a console.

There are neither errors nor warnings in my journal, dmesg, and the xorg logs, apart from a section where X appears to find which modules are available, 
Where the ones that aren't installed throw an error - however, there's a warning saying the Nvidia driver couldn't get a display DPI. (Perhaps I can manage to get a paste in a while. )

My hardware setup consists of a GeForce Gt730m with the `nvidia` driver and an onboard intel card.

I don't have an XOrg config other than one file setting keyboard parameters.

What can I do to further debug this?